# Can anyone tell me what this section of pseudocode is doing?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering

Can anyone tell me what this section of pseudocode is doing?
I produced it use IDA Pro

Thanks in advance!

```
int __cdecl sub_401000(int a1, int a2)
{
  int result; // eax@4                                                        
  int v3; // [sp+0h] [bp-Ch]@4                                                
  char v4; // [sp+7h] [bp-5h]@4                                               
  int i; // [sp+8h] [bp-4h]@1                                                 
  signed int v6; // [sp+8h] [bp-4h]@4                                         

  for ( i = 0; *(_BYTE *)(i + a1); ++i )
    ;
  result = i - 1;
  v6 = i - 1;
  v3 = 0;
  v4 = -1;
  while ( v4 )
  {
    v4 = *(_BYTE *)(v6 + a1);
    result = a2;
    *(_WORD *)(a2 + 2 * v3) = ((unsigned __int8)byte_40A300[v6 % 4] ^ *(_BYTE *)(v6 +     a1)) & 0x7F;
    --v6;
    ++v3;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `for` loop finds the length of string `a1`. The following `while` loop then transforms the bytes of `a1` by XORing them with a 4 byte constant key, and widening to UTF16 (presumably). The result is written reversed into `a2`.